# Good movies to watch for the sound design?

Tags: movies, sound-design

Quick question... What movies do you recommend any of us watch for good sound design?

Comment: we've already got a thread covering this. check out http://socialsounddesign.com/questions/2032/films-to-study-for-excellence-in-sound-design, it should have what you're looking for.

Comment: Well, crap.  That's embarrassing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A quick advice: don't limitate yourself to just see "films with good sound"... Almost any film will teach you something, even if it's a silent movie.. You can learn a lot from from bad sounding films, or good ones, or oscar winning productions, independent films, trailers, documentary, etc.